# Unable to install nova compute. Error in command: python setup.py install

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, pip, openstack, openstack-nova

I am unable to install Nova-Compute. 
When I run the python setup.py install command there is an error in parsing. I am not getting the problem. I did'nt change the setup.cfg file. I even tried replacing with the old nova setup.cfg file.

**This is the error**

```
> bash-4.2# python setup.py install
> error in setup command: Error parsing /sagar/nova/setup.cfg: LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `utf_8` not `utf-8`

Check [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for more info

Comment: I think that is not the issue. That is already used in availability_zones.py and utils.py packages. I tried changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error but for another OpenStack service. Try to set your locale manually, for example, execute this in your shell:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

you can also add this line into your .bashrc file.